# 502 bad gateway php7.0-fpm nginx when sleep in php script - ab benchmark test

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

502 error occurs when I test apache benchmark on php script on different server. max_children error
run ab at server a

```
ab -kc 1000 -n 10000 http:// serverB.com/fun.php
```

php file (fun.php) on server B

```
<?php
    sleep(300);
?>
```

I use nginx with php7.0 fpm